# How to Subtract a Date in Varchar with a System Date?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to subtract two dates in a query in order to give me the number of years of a person and make changes in the status of old  if it passes the age defined(4 years in this case) I have this:

```
$date = date('Y'); //get current year
$ageDefined = 4;
$personDateofBirth = 1945;

$query="update animal set old = '1' where *help here*
```

Can you tell me how to do the math properly? Thanks :)